# Reason why the time taken to execute below code snippets differ a lot?

Tags: java, loops, long-integer, autoboxing

Consider the code snippets below and the time taken to execute them -

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long sum = 0L;
    for(int i = 0; i< Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
        sum+=i;
    }
    Long timeDiff = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
    System.out.println("Time Difference : " + timeDiff + "secs");
}
```

Output -

> **Time Difference : 0secs**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Long sum = 0L;
    for(int i = 0; i< Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
        sum+=i;
    }
    Long timeDiff = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
    System.out.println("Time Difference : " + timeDiff + "secs");
}
```

Output -

> **Time Difference : 8secs**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Long sum = 0L;
    for(Long i = 0L; i< Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
        sum+=i;
    }
    Long timeDiff = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
    System.out.println("Time Difference : " + timeDiff + "secs");
}
```

Output -

> **Time Difference : 16secs**

As per my understanding, it's happening because of every time object creation of Long Object, I am not sure how exactly this is happening. Tried looking into byte code didn't help much. 
Help me understand how exactly things are internally happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess your explanation is correct. Is this a question about identifying where in each snippet auto-boxing and auto-unboxing happens?

Comment: I am not sure about that but if that answers about the times taken above then it might be yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "++" and "+=" operators are only defined for primitives.

Hence, when you apply them to a `Long`, an unboxing must take place before the operator is evaluated and then a boxing must take place to store the result.

The boxing probably costs more than the unboxing, since unboxing requires just a method call, while boxing requires object instantiation.

Each boxing involves the creation of a `Long` instance. Your loop has `Integer.MAX_VALUE` iterations, so the second loop creates  over 2 billion `Long` objects (one for each `sum+=i` operation) while the third loop creates over 4 billion `Long` objects (one for each `i++` operation and one for each `sum+=i` operation). These objects have to be instantiated and later garbage collected. That costs time.

Answer (score 2):

Plausible causes:
 - Too many object creations leading to **GC activity** at times.
 - Too many boxing and unboxing of Wrapper to primitive and vice versa.